# Does anyone knows how can I find this gradient?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, vector-analysis

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DegCh.png)

Does anyone know how can I start to find the gradient of this function?
Any help or hint would be appreciated.

Comment: What do they mean by external definition?

Comment: The expression df(x) =〈g(x),dx〉is known as the external definition of the gradient

Comment: Do you know how to solve it without the use of the external definition?

Comment: It would be 2*A^T(Ax)

Comment: T as transpose.

Answer (score 0):

The explicit form of the function is:

$$ f(x_1,x_2,...,x_n) = \sum_{i=1}^m \sqrt{ \left( \sum_{k=1}^n A_{ik} \thinspace x_k \right)^2 + \epsilon}$$

Applying the chain rule we have:

$$(\nabla f(x_1,x_2,...,x_n))_j = \sum_{i=1}^m - \frac{2 \thinspace A_{ij} \left( \sum_{k=1}^n A_{ik} \thinspace x_{k} \right)}{2 \sqrt{ \left( \sum_{k=1}^n A_{ik} \thinspace x_k \right)^2 + \epsilon}} \quad \forall \thinspace j \in \{1,...,n\}$$